# How do I write tests for torando handler wrapped with stream_body decorator?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tornado

I have an async handler, wrapped with ["stream_body" decorator](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.stream_request_body), which is used for receiving big files and reading them incrementally similar to [this example](https://gist.github.com/bdarnell/5bb1bd04a443c4e06ccd). However, I don't understand, how can I test this functionality in unittest, as this requires an async client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test a handler that uses `stream_request_body` without any special features in the client. For example, [this test in Tornado itself](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/0721917e5078e0937d2cd5f8355aa9301df4ca06/tornado/test/web_test.py#L2213-L2220) tests a `stream_request_body` handler with an ordinary request (which happens to be sent with an AsyncHTTPClient because that's how AsyncHTTPTestCase does things, but it could in principle be done with a synchronous client in another thread).

If you want to test the streaming properties of the handler, then you may need a more flexible client. For example, [a test that uses `body_producer`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/0721917e5078e0937d2cd5f8355aa9301df4ca06/tornado/test/web_test.py#L2222-L2234) in `AsyncHTTPClient` can control the sending of chunks without uploading everything as fast as possible.